# Socket error on reading from client

Tags: c++, tcp

I have a TCP client that gives `bad address` error. I think is related to this point of the code, but even trying all kind of possibilites, i cannot make it work:

```
n=recv(sockfd,&buffer[0],1000,0);
```

buffer is defined as: `std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;` and it's resized to 1000 before I enter in the read loop. How could i fix it?

-----------EDIT

```
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

I'm aware of the error caused by the `clilen` declaration, so this is how i do it:

```
socklen_t clilen= sizeof(cli_addr);
```

----SOLUTION:

I had set `NONBLOCKING` mode before creating the socket, that was creating a malfunction.

Comment: What value is n set to after recv returns?

Comment: Please post the source to your `accept()` call.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The value of `n7 is -1.
@AndyBrown code posted.
Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `errno` after you get the -1? Or the message printed by `perror()`?

Comment: @EJP `bad address`

Comment: Your 'solution' is nonsense. You *can't* set non-blocking mode before creating a socket, and doing so does not cause 'bad address' errors.

Comment: well sherlock, looks like I can, i had this program working for long time, but on the scenario of "client receiving data, not sending" it didnt work. I dont care if it's nonsense or whatever, it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n=recv(sockfd,&buffer[0],1000,0);
```

The problem is here. You're receiving on the listening socket. It should be:

```
n=recv(newsockfd,&buffer[0],1000,0);
```

Comment: Im afraid no. The first `recv()` is from the client side and the `accept()` is from the server side

Comment: The only evidence provided in your question shows clearly that you are calling `recv()` on a listening socket. If you are calling it on another socket, in another process, after code you haven't posted yet, presumably you failed to create it or connect it. Your question needs clarification. Clarify it.